# Google fonts URL break HTML5 Validation on w3.org

Tags: html, w3c-validation, google-font-api

I load 3 fonts in different sizes using this HTML tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,800,700,400italic|PT+Serif:400,400italic|Bree+Serif">
```

Till ~1/2 weeks ago this was supported by [w3.org validator](http://validator.w3.org/) for HTML5; now it gives this error:

```
 Line 14, Column 163: Bad value http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,800,700,400italic|PT+Serif:400,400italic|Bree+Serif for attribute href on element link: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.
```

What's the things the W3C Markup Validator does not like now?

Answer (score 358, accepted):

URL encode the `|` (pipe characters) in the `href` attribute (`%7C`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,800,700,400italic%7CPT+Serif:400,400italic%7CBree+Serif">
```

Comment: Is this an issue with Google generated URL or an issue with w3 validator? Does any spec actually require pipe character to be encoded in HTML attribute?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen, [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) notes that the pipe character is unsafe: Other characters are unsafe because
   gateways and other transport agents are known to sometimes modify
   such characters. These characters are "{", "}", "|", "\", "^", "~",
   "[", "]", and "`".

Comment: I would expect raw UTF-8 to be valid in UTF-8 encoded HTML without encoding other characters but those used for HTML e.g. `&`,
 `"` and `'`. And those special characters would need to be encoded by HTML rules (e.g. `&amp` etc). The user agent is then expected to follow RFC 3987 and convert the IRI to percent encoded UTF-8  before submitting it over HTTP (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3987).

Comment: Interestingly, my Google Font link to Open Sans didn't contain a pipe, but rather a blank between "Open" and "Sans". Replacing the blank by a "+" solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways to fix this validation problem:

1. URL encode the `|` (vertical bar/line) character in the `href` attribute of the `link` element (as `%7C`) :

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,800,700,400italic%7CPT+Serif:400,400italic%7CBree+Serif">
   ```
2. Separate fonts inclusion with multiple `link` elements :

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,800,700,400italic">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,400italic">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif">
   ```

Comment: I know this is older post, but does anyone know if there is any performance (dis)advantage to separating `<link>` tags? Does Google compress if multiple fonts are in one call?

Comment: @PatrickMoore 2 things: **a)** your server upload/response speed vs your end-user download speed **b)** time to create another connection (server response time vs end-user response time), theoretically, if you are loading 2 "heavy" fonts and your page is otherwise loading fast, loading them separately (in a paralel way) could result in faster load. But it really depends on a) & b)

Answer (score 6):

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

You must replace the character | by its corresponding UTF-8 character, which gives

```
href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie%7cAmaranth%7cKaushan+Script%7cCousine%7cBilbo+Swash+Caps%7cRancho&amp;effect=shadow-multiple"
```

Answer (score -3):

My case was crazy line break character.  Please see the attached image.[image]

Answer (score -4):

I scape **&** with "**& amp;**" and works fine, example:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

Comment: This question is about `|` character, not `&` ;-)