# How to pass "|" symbol in Axios URL?

Tags: axios

```
url=`https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/HiThere/${firstName}|${lastName}`
```

I'm passing this but during request its changing to `https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/HiThere/${firstName}%7C${lastName}`

Comment: send it as `%7C` then! `url=https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/HiThere/${firstName}%7C${lastName}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle escape characters (pipe |) in URL (Spring, REST, CXF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940826/how-to-handle-escape-characters-pipe-in-url-spring-rest-cxf)

Answer (score 2):

> How to pass “|” symbol in Axios URL?

Be certain that you are *getting* it correctly, and not converting it.

See: [How to prevent Axios from encoding my request parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116731/how-to-prevent-axios-from-encoding-my-request-parameters), [Getting Started With Axios](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-axios-166cb0035237), or [Get parameter array with key value](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1093).

The "encoding" ought to be done in the standard manner, it's up to the decoder to 'do the right thing'.

See: [HTML URL Encoding Reference - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), [URL Encoding | Maps URLs | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/url-encoding) or [Google fonts URL break HTML5 Validation on w3.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466913/google-fonts-url-break-html5-validation-on-w3-org).

The pipe is encoded as: %7C

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use < > # % { } | \ ^ ~ [ ] characters in a url safely. 
Please check this [link](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/) for more information regarding which all characters can be used safely. So either you have to change the symbol or decode the '%7C'.